# How to refer less file for compilation only?

Tags: css, less

I want to import some less files for reference only to use mixins and other variables from that less in my project related less files.
I have tried:

```
@import(reference) filename.less
```

But it is appending styling of `filename.less` file also when the the project related less files are compiled to corresponding css files.

Comment: what if you split imported file in two: one containing mixins and other with styles?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format.

```
@import (reference) "filename";
```

I'm using this in my projects, and it does not compile the referenced file.

Comment: Thanks Tania for your answer. What version of the LESS you are using for compiling